# maintain mvc architecutre in Spring MVCf 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two tables that have relationship like

tbl_department whose entities are dept_id and dept_name where dept_id is primary key and next table is tbl_employee whose entities are emp_id, emp_name and dept_id where dept_id is foreign key that references the dept_id of tbl_department. Now, in my jsp page i want to display the format like this:

Emp_id|Emp_name|dept_name.

I am doing above display in JSP page using the JSTL sql tag, and I know it violates the MVC architecture, so, how could I solve this problem i.e. how can I do this relationship mapping it in either Model or Controller in Spring instead in JSP page. Is there any examples or tutorial I can find for this kind of problem

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide whether it would be worth your while using [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org). You should research this yourself to decide whether the rest of your app would benefit from using it (too big a topic to address here).

Assuming you only want to do the use case you have outlined in the question, I'd suggest you use Spring's [JDBC support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) and create a Service (or just a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)) to perform the SQL that you are currently using in your JSP. I'd create a simple [DTO class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to hold the `Emp_id|Emp_name|dept_name` data and populate that in your Service/DAO and then pass it to the JSP via the Controller.

This [Spring MVC Example (skeleton) app](https://github.com/mikaelhg/springmvc-example) would be a good place to start, to see how those components are created and wired together.